# Autocomplete concept

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm programming a search engine for my website in PHP, SQL and JQuery. I have experience in adding autocomplete with existing data in the database (i.e. searching article titles). But what about if I want to use the most common search queries that the users type, something similar to the one Google has, without having so much users to contribute to the creation of the data (most common queries)? Is there some kind of open-source SQL table with autocomplete data in it or something similar?

Comment: If that's your question, why not have your subject reflect it?

Comment: Why would you need some unspecified open source autocomplete data, if none of those terms are actually in your own database. You should only use those search terms, for which you could have a match in your database.

Comment: that was one of my questions: how do I create my own data if i'm the only one using this search engine at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I stumbled on something that answered my question. Google draws autocomplete suggestions from this XML file, so it is wise to use it if you have little users to create your own database with keywords:

```
http://google.com/complete/search?q=[keyword]&output=toolbar
```

Just replacing [keyword] with some word will give suggestions about that word then the taks is just to parse the returned xml and format the output to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

1. As of now use the static data that you have for auto complete.
2. Create another table in your database to store the actual user queries. The schema of the table can be `<queryID, query, count>` where count is incremented each time same query is supplied by some other user [Kind of Rank]. N-Gram Index (so that you could also auto-complete something like "Manchester United" when person just types "United", i.e. not just with the starting string) the queries and simply return the top N after sorting using count.
3. The above table will gradually keep on improving as and when your user base starts increasing.
4. One more thing, the Algorithm for accomplishing your task is pretty simple. However the real challenge lies in returning the data to be displayed in fraction of seconds. So when your query database/store size increases then you can use a search engine like Solr/Sphinx to search for you which will be pretty fast in returning back the results to be rendered.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was looking for. But the question of having millions users to filter the search results is still open. What if a certain user wants to spam and enters 100 times Manchester Untitled instead of Manchester United? There will be not enough users who really search for Manchester United to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Lucene]You can use Lucene Search Engiine for this functionality.Refer this [link](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Enabling_autocomplete_in_search_box)

or you may also give look to Lucene Solr Autocomplete...

Comment: Yes, he could – but that doesn't solve the problem: what to show at the beginning, when having no user-base…

Answer (score 0):

Google has (and having) thousands of entries which are arranged according to (day, time, geolocation, language....) and it is increasing by the entries of users, whenever user types a word the system checks the table of "mostly used words belonged to that location+day+time" + (if no answer) then "general words". So for that you should categorize every word entered by users, or make general word-relation table of you database, where the most suitable searched answer will be referenced to.

Comment: that's very effective ... if you have billions of users entering trillions of querys every minute .. but what about a start-up with only few dozen users?

Comment: For a few dozens of users I suggest SQLite as a backend database for autocomplete strings. And for the "100 times Manchester Untitled" matter try to use "probabilistic mathematics" where you have a database of prevously entered search strings database and comparing which of them is near the the string a user entered. Search for Levenstein Algorithm for that and maybe Percepron Algorithm may also help you.